# why are my all my brushes producing spikey results to my model?

Tags: brushes

[image]so I cnt+J two objects and remeshed in sculpt mode.  When i use the draw or grab brushes i get this spikey brush result? i applied scale in object mode, not sure how to fix it, please help!

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please do share your file with the current brush settings.. ( It doesn't have to be the whole mesh if that's too big)